# What property is used for calculating data age for enforcing retention policy of an ADX table

Tags: azure-data-explorer

I guess retention happens at extent level , so what timestamp is used for determining age of data to be purged? Is it the property **MaxCreatedOn** ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps that happens for an extent

1. Removal from the table also known as "soft delete", this does not means deletion, it means that the data is not available for query
2. Actual deletion of the data from storage based on the recoverability property

For soft delete there’s a background process that runs up to once an hour, and drops (soft deletes) all extents that are older (according to MaxCreatedOn) than X hours, where X is taken from the soft delete period set in the effective retention policy.

The actual deletion of the data is an optimized process where the extents are grouped into containers based on a day and the whole container is dropped based on soft delete period and the recoverability setting.

see more in the [retention policy docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/kusto/management/retentionpolicy)